# getting rid of whitespaces in heredoc

Tags: php

I am having this loop

```
foreach ($unserialized as $key => $value) {
 $foo = <<<EOT
<div class='krudItem' id='xxx'><form class='aj' name='itemForm' method='post'
 action=''><section><label>Slider Title</label><input type='hidden'
 name='sliderKey' value=$key/><input type='text' name='sliderTitle' value='$value 
 ['slidertitle']'/></section><section> <label>Slider Location</label>
 <input type='text' 
 name=$value['sliderlocation']value='ipsum'/></section><section><label>Slider 
 Description</label><textarea name='sliderDescription'>$value
 ['sliderdescription']</textarea></section><button name='saveNew' class='saveNew' 
 value='save'>save</button><button name='newCancel' value='cancel' 
 class='deleteNew'>cancel</button></form></div>
EOT;
echo $foo;
```

but everytime i run it,i get

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),

I have been reading what php says about https://www.php.net/tokens and i have tried every other possible solution but the error persists.There are some white spaces but i am not sure how i would deal with them well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enclose your variables in curly braces:

```
$str = <<<EOF
some string with {$some['variables']} in it
EOF;
```

You can put any PHP expression in `{...}` as long as it starts with a `$`.

See [the documentation on this syntax at php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#example-72).

Answer (score 2):

You need to encase your variables in brackets.

This should work for you:

```
<?php
foreach ($unserialized as $key => $value) {
    $foo = <<<EOT
    <div class='krudItem' id='xxx'>
        <form class='aj' name='itemForm' method='post' action=''>
            <section>
                <label>Slider Title</label>
                <input type='hidden' name='sliderKey' value={$key}/>
                <input type='text' name='sliderTitle' value='{$value['slidertitle']}'/>
            </section>
            <section>
                <label>Slider Location</label>
                <input type='text' name={$value['sliderlocation']} value='ipsum'/>
            </section>
            <section>
                <label>Slider Description</label>
                <textarea name='sliderDescription'>
                    {$value['sliderdescription']}
                </textarea>
            </section>
            <button name='saveNew' class='saveNew' value='save'>save</button>
            <button name='newCancel' value='cancel' class='deleteNew'>cancel</button>
        </form>
    </div>
EOT;
    echo $foo;
}
```

Comment: Really? You've changed all HTML attribute names into variable interpolations, are you sure about this?

Comment: Sublime plugin that did it :S